# Rules for scale specific layer style in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, style, scale

I've got a very large polygon land cover map (millions of polygons) over a large area. Our first try at serving the data through GeoServer WMS was not very successful due to the large amount of small polygons. So it was suggested to use scale specific styling (along with spatial indexes) to show only the larger polygons at a broader scale and refine as the user zooms in. This process of setting which polygons appears at each scale, based on polygon size, is a trial and error approach? Or are there rules that one could follow in order to identify which features to display depending on the scale?

Comment: you can use a combination of MaxScaleDenominator and MinScaleDenominator Rules with a normal comparison Rules (if you know the area of the polygons)

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-reference/filters.html#comparison-operators

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-reference/rules.html

Comment: I understood how to set the style using Max(Min)ScaleDenominator. My question is more in the sense of what is the minimal polygon area to display at each scale. Are there some rules of thumb to define which polygons to draw? Or trial and error?